# Module parse failed: error: semantic/dist/semantic.min.css Unexpected character '@' (11:0)

Tags: webpack, semantic-ui, react-boilerplate, semantic-ui-react

I use the current version of react-boilerplate (which uses webpack) and installed Semantic-UI-React like described in the official docs http://react.semantic-ui.com/usage

When I start the server I get:

```
Server started ! ✓

Access URLs:
-----------------------------------
Localhost: http://localhost:3000
      LAN: http://192.168.100.103:3000
-----------------------------------
Press CTRL-C to stop

webpack built dba595efb772df0727e8 in 11657ms

ERROR in ./semantic/dist/semantic.min.css
Module parse failed: /Users/standardnerd/development/template/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css Unexpected character '@' (11:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  *
|  */
| @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin);/*!
|  * # Semantic UI 2.2.7 - Reset
|  * http://github.com/semantic-org/semantic-ui/
 @ ./app/app.js 20:0-43
 @ multi main
```

What kind of 'appropriate loader' do I need?

The parser doesn't like the @import statement in /semantic/dist/semantic.min.css:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin);
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve the issue with installing sass-loader - since I'm gonna using scss anyway.

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev
```

rename `./semantic/dist/semantic.min.css` to `./semantic/dist/semantic.min.scss`
and modifying the config:

```
    test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'style-loader',
      }, {
        loader: 'css-loader',
      }, {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
      }],
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using an include directive in the rule make sure to include also node_modules:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader'],
  include: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    /node_modules/
  ],
},
```

That should fix the problem as it you're instructing webpack to make sure to include node modules when loading css so that it can properly utilize the css-loader when importing the semantic ui css package.

Answer (score 3):

Step1:  Install following packages

`npm install --save-dev css-loader sass-loader node-sass url-loader file-loader`

Step2:  Then, in webpack.config.js file:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
            loader: 'sass-loader!style-loader!css-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
        }
    ]
}
```

Step3:  In modules,

If you installed semantic css via npm package `npm install --save-dev semantic-ui-css`, then import entry should be `import './node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'`

Use relavent import statment if you have not installed `semantic-ui-css` via npm.